# Getting PlotLegend to show the exponential of values?

Tags: plotting, legending

I made a contour plot in Mathematica, and am currently using PlotLegends->Automatic. But, instead of having the legend labels show the values of the function, I want it to show the Exp of the function. How can I do this?

Here is my code and the label I get:

```
ContourPlot[
 Log[n1[2.772861961857343*10^-6, .9, 2.8, a, b, .6, .3, .5]], 
 {b, 1, 3}, {a, .5, 1.5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"π", "β"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(\[Lambda]1\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(1\)]\)=0.9", 
 Contours -> 10, 
 ColorFunction -> "CandyColors"]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to have the definition of your function `n1`

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using `ScalingFunctions->"Log"` instead of manually taking the logarithm of your expression? (Beacuse then, the plot legend values are accurate)

Comment: That worked! Thank you @LukasLang